# Ubuntu 16.04> Dell monitor 'inport timing not supported'

Tags: display, monitor, display-resolution, amd-graphics, multiple-monitors

I have been trying to upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 and more recently Ubuntu 16.10 Beta 2. Unfortunately, I have been unable to get both of my Dell U2312HM monitors working at their native resolution of 1920×1080 at the same time. One of the monitors will report 'The current input timing is not supported by the monitor display. Please change your input timing to 1920x1080@60Hz or any other monitor listed timing as per the monitor specifications' ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23Vx2.jpg)). Both monitors show up in the settings and can be set to 1920×1080, as long as the other is set to a lower resolution. I am using an R9 380 graphics card.

I don't remember if the issue was always present in Ubuntu 15.10, but it could always be resolved by installing fglrx. However, this display driver is deprecated as of Ubuntu 16.04, and I am now using amdgpu. Since 15.10 is no longer supported, and I would hate to move all the way back to 14.04, I hope to resolve this issue and stay on 16.x. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'd recommend filing a bug report. You can report it at the following places: https://bugs.freedesktop.org (DRI DRM/AMDgpu), https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+filebug